# why is this if let code in Swift Xcode 10.1 throwing a Thread 1: signal SIGABART

Tags: swift

This code in Swift Xcode 10.1 keeps throwing a Thread 1: signal SIGABART error and I don't know why.

```
    let item = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "To Does")
    var arrayItem:[String]
    print("about to check")
    if let arrayItem2 = item as! [String]?{

        arrayItem = arrayItem2
        arrayItem.append(textInput.text!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayItem, forKey: "To Does")
        print(arrayItem)

    }else{
        UserDefaults.standard.set(textInput.text!, forKey: "To Does")
    }
    textInput.text = ""
```

Comment: Why use force cast when you are already using `if let` anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use a forced cast with `if let`. Never force cast to an optional. Neither make any sense.

Even once you fix that you have a problem. You first write a string to user defaults if there is nothing yet for the key. But then you try to read an array. That will never work.

Simplify your code and always write an read an array.

```
var items = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "To Does") as? [String] ?? []
items.append(textInput.text!)
UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "To Does")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing an `item` to console. Chances are it's neither `nil`, nor an `[String]` and it fails a forced cast.

If it's not - you can use a simpler cast. Try this in playground:

```
let item: Any? = 2
var arrayItem: [String] = []
print("about to check")
if let arrayItem2 = item as? [String] {

    arrayItem = arrayItem2
    arrayItem.append("foo")
    print(arrayItem)
} else {
    print("doing nothing")
}
```

Outputs:

```
about to check
doing nothing
```